# ActiveRecord Missing From clause for mutlipe where conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have this nested include structure

```
Converter. 
 includes(:converter_params, user: [:address]).
 where('converters.is_active=? AND converter_params.date >= ?', true, 3.month.ago)
```

which is working without 
the `AND converter_params.date` condition. Adding this gets the error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "converter_params"
```

The table `converter_prams` exists and the name is correct.
I am unable to figure out why, many thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Having a model named `Controller` in a MVC app sounds like a recipe for disaster.

Comment: :D its not actually Controller, is just wanted to make it a bit more generic, but i agree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you should explicitly give a reference for :converter_params table:

```
Converter. 
 includes(:converter_params, user: [:address]).
 where('converters.is_active=? AND converter_params.date >= ?', true, 3.month.ago).references(:converter_params)
```

"For SQL-fragments you need to use references to force joined tables:" as stated [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations)

Comment: hah! Many thanks!. I think i have to buy some pair of glasses or something, becuse i remember reading about this also !!